# Problemas com arquivos em C

Tags: c

Olá, gente!
Estou fazendo um código para cadastro de pacientes que testaram positivo para a covid. Quando o paciente for cadastrado, os seus dados são enviados para um arquivo txt. O problema acontece quando um paciente tem mais de 65 anos e deve ter seus dados gravados em outro arquivo separado dos outros pacientes.
No momento de checar a idade e gravar os dados em outro arquivo, tenho problemas na hora da gravação. Não consigo que fique gravado no arquivo que eu quero.
Sou iniciante em C e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

A partir do uso do if é possível criar um outro arquivo para colocar os dados do paciente que tem mais de 65 anos?

```
void inputPaciente(){
    PACIENTE pct;
    FILE* arquivo;
    
    arquivo = fopen("lista_pacientes.txt", "ab");
    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo.");
    }
    else{
        do{   
              cabecalho();
              
              printf("\nINSIRA OS DADOS DO PACIENTE\n");
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nNome: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.nome);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nCPF: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.CPF);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nTelefone: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.telefone);

              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nEndereço completo: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.endereco);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nCEP: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.CEP);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nData De nascimento (DD/MM/AAAA): ");
              scanf("%d %d %d", &pct.aniv.dia, &pct.aniv.mes, &pct.aniv.ano);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nDigite o email do paciente: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.email);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nData do diagnostico (DD/MM/AAAA): ");
              scanf("%s", pct.dataDoDiagnostico);
              
              fflush(stdin);
              printf("\nO paciente possui alguma comorbidade?: ");
              scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.comorbidade);
              
              fwrite(&pct, sizeof(PACIENTE), 1, arquivo);
              
              printf("\nDeseja continuar (s/n)?");
              
        }while(getche() == 's');
        fclose(arquivo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você quiser gravar em outro arquivo então precisa ter um outro arquivo (declarar, abrir, gravar e fechar), sua rotina trabalha com um único arquivo.

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei como e em qual momento do código eu devo fazer isso.

Comment: Onde tiver uma referência à `arquivo` faça a mesma coisa com, por exemplo, `arquivo65`. Trate sua `dataDoDiagnostico` não como uma string mas como composta dos campos dia, mês e ano. Antes de gravar verifique se a data de nascimento é <= data do diagnóstico - 65 anos e grave ou em arquivo ou em arquivo65.

Comment: Acho que você não deveria gravar em outro arquivo, isso deveria ser uma propriedade do objeto "Paciente". E eu não conseguir entender no que existe c# na sua dúvida...

Comment: Agora entendi o que deve ser feito. Obrigada, gente!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sempre que você escrever qualquer coisa dentro do arquivo você tem que usar a função fflush e colocar o arquivo como parâmetro, se não ele não vai salvar.
Exemplo:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", pct.comorbidade);
          
          fwrite(&pct, sizeof(PACIENTE), 1, arquivo);
          fflush(arquivo);
          printf("\nDeseja continuar (s/n)?");
```

Veja essa referência: http://www.cmaismais.com.br/referencia/cstdio/fflush/

Comment: O usuário com [um ponto de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) possui o [privilégio de criar publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts). Destaque na descrição do privilégio: *O privilégio mais básico de todos, o direito de fazer uma pergunta e o direito de contribuir com uma resposta. Isso geralmente está disponível para qualquer pessoa, independentemente do nível de reputação.*.

Comment: Não use o site principal para fazer reclamações de funcionamento, para isso existe o [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Os debates abertos no *META* devem ser sobre o funcionamento do site, perguntas a comunidade, bugs, propostas de melhorias e novos recursos. Leia: [O que é o "META"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)